# Slide Panel Up and Down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nuLfekdf/2/):

```
<div class="panel" id="map">
  <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/880x120"/>    
</div>
<div class="panel" id="text">
  <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div class="content">
  <a href="#map" id="open-map" class="trigger">Open Map</a><br>
  <a href="#text" id="open-map" class="trigger">Open Text</a>
  <p>
    Integer mattis felis in felis eleifend ...       
  </p>
</div>

#map {border: solid 1px red;}

#text {border: solid 1px blue;}

img {display: block;}

div.panel {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;    
}

div.panel a {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: @red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I need the following:

1. When a trigger is clicked slide down / up toggle the panel with id the same as in its href.
2. When the button Close inside a panel is clicked slide up that panel.

I was able to kind of solve it using the following:

```
$('#open-map').click(function(){
    var $helper = $('#map');
    $helper.animate({
        height: "toggle"
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        progress: function(){
           $helper.scrollTop( $helper[0].scrollHeight );       
        }
    });
});
```

1. I do not know how to use the Trigger class and how to make the Close work.
2. I am also not sure if animate is the best option.

Comment: You can make the whole slide up/down as one function and call that on click. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/nuLfekdf/3/)

Comment: [this should work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/nuLfekdf/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One further approach, which makes it a little more expandable (so long as you associate the `<a>` elements' `href` attribute with the `id` of the targeted element) is:

```
// binding a click-handler to the <a class="close"> elements:
$('a.close').on('click', function (e) {
    // slide-toggling the closest <div class="panel"> ancestor element,
    // although slideUp() could be used, since if the element is hidden the
    // a.close element can't be clicked:
    $(this).closest('.panel').slideToggle();
});

// binding a click handler to the .trigger elements:
$('.trigger').on('click', function () {
    // getting a reference to the clicked-element:
    var clicked = $(this),
        // forming an array of all the sibling .trigger elements,
        ids = clicked.siblings('.trigger')
                  // adding back the clicked element:
                  .addBack().map(function () {
                      return this.getAttribute('href');
                  }).get();
    // finding all the elements associated with those .trigger elements:
    $(ids.join(',')).each(function () {
        // iterating over the collection with each(),
        // if the href attribute (not property) of the clicked element
        // contains the string of the id of the current element at
        // an index of 1:
        if (clicked.attr('href').indexOf(this.id) === 1) {
            // we slideToggle() the relevant element:
            $(this).slideToggle();
        } else {
            // otherwise we simply close the element:
            $(this).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$('a.close').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.panel').slideToggle();
});

$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
  var clicked = $(this),
    ids = clicked.siblings('.trigger').addBack().map(function() {
      return this.getAttribute('href');
    }).get();
  $(ids.join(',')).each(function() {
    if (clicked.attr('href').indexOf(this.id) === 1) {
      $(this).slideToggle();
    } else {
      $(this).slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none;
}
.trigger {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="map"> <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/880x120" />
</div>
<div class="panel" id="text"> <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce imperdiet, urna id dignissim venenatis, mi metus convallis purus, et tincidunt nunc leo sit amet lectus. Nullam vitae efficitur purus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent mauris massa, ullamcorper ut
  varius vitae, porttitor id augue.</div>
<div class="content"> <a href="#map" id="open-map" class="trigger">Open Map</a>
  <a href="#text" id="open-text" class="trigger">Open Text</a>

</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute).
  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- jQuery:

  - [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).
  - [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Answer (score 2):

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nuLfekdf/4/)**

```
$('#open-map').click(function(){
    $('#map').slideToggle('slow');
});
$('#open-text').click(function(){
    $('#text').slideToggle('slow');
});
$('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp('slow');
});
```

Works for map and text both.

Comment: I like your solution ... Really simple. But what is the difference to animate? And how to have a more generic approach as I described using the href? I am asking this because I might have 10 panels ... And it also makes it easier when changing something in html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#close-map').click(function(){
var $helper = $('#map');
$helper.animate({
            height: "toggle"
        }, {
        duration: 200,
        progress: function(){
            $helper.scrollTop( $helper[0].scrollHeight );       
        }
    });
});
```

just add this block to make close link work , where **#close-map** is id of close link