# Dynamic view on a sliding panel with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have you ever seen someone's code and just laughed? Be ready to do so with my jQuery as it may not make any sense to you, but I'm trying :)

Anyway, what I need is simple and I've gotten some inspiration from other questions here such as [Slide Panel up and down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547370/slide-panel-up-and-down) but they don't do exactly what I need. At least methinks.

I have a panel immediately below my header (BOOTSTRAP). This panel needs to be there but the user must have a choice to close it a little, **not the whole way**. Just enough to still have the fa-chevron icon available to click it and slide it back down as well as some information (I'll provide images below).

So in a nutshell, the requirements are:

- Starts open, fa-chevron-up
- On icon click, the panel slides up (sort of slowish), hides the photo and second row of information, and switches the icon to fa-chevron-down.
- On click of fa-chevron down (collapsed view) everything returns to the initial full view.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="header" class="header navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" data-current-theme="navbar-inverse">
</div>  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="banner clearfix">
            <div class="collapser">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-fw collapse-icon"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="banner-info clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                    <div class="circle-container">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTGjucaoN3fabOcumnr7RKTB3ICTJFLuLClnpiQUIR9oW4a11wb" alt="offender-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Full Name</label>
                            <span>Floyd "Money" Mayweather</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Some Label</label>
                            <span>Something Here</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Offender ID#</label>
                            <span>123569863</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Longer Label Example</label>
                            <span>Something Here with an ellipsis</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Institution</label>
                            <span>Graterford</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Some Link</label>
                            <a href="#"><span>Something Here</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Institution</label>
                            <span>Graterford</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Some Link</label>
                            <span href="#"><p>Something Here</p></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.navbar {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #30373e;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.025);
    box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.025);
    z-index: 1040;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 55px;
}

.banner {
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #101113;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    top: 55px;
}

.banner .collapser {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    color: #bbb;
}

.banner .circle-container {
    position: relative;
    left: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -ms-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #bbb;
}

.banner .banner-info label {
    color: rgba(248,151,29,0.77);
}

.banner .banner-info span {
    display: block;
    color: #bbb;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 85%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and the very vague and probably useless JS

```
$('.collapser').click(function () {
    $collapser = $(this);
    $banner = $collapser.parent().find('.banner');

    $banner.slideToggle(500, function () {
        $collapser.find('.collapse-icon').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });
});
```

Here are both views for visual references

Initial view
[image]

collapsed view
[image]

And here is [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/GoOYEX)

Comment: This doesn't seem to follow the requirements of a good SO question. You should address the specific problem and seek solutions for each replicable problem vs stating requirements and have us do it for you. To get you started, use jquery's `hide()` in your click function to hide the picture then change the css of your banner to the size that will collapse it to what you need. Make sure you use `overflow: hidden` on the banner

Comment: Oh Gee! You'd think after being in SO and having the reputation I have, I would know how to ask a question here! HA Silly of me. My apologies @Douglas_Symb lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `.banner` elements appears as child of `$collapser.parent()` ?

Try changing `.banner` to `.banner-info` at `$banner = $collapser.parent().find(".banner-info");`

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrXYGx

---

> Is there a way to slide it up less than that? or would that be a whole
>   different deal? Because I can hide the photo and the second row if I
>   mess with it long enough, but I still need the first row to remain
>   visible.

Use selector `$banner = $collapser.parent().find('.banner-info .circle-container, .col-md-10 > .col-md-3 > .form-group:nth-of-type(2)')` as `$banner` collection

```
$('.collapser').click(function() {
    $collapser = $(this);
    $banner = $collapser.parent()
             .find('.banner-info .circle-container\
                  , .col-md-10 > .col-md-3 > .form-group:nth-of-type(2)');

    $banner.slideToggle(500, function() {
        $collapser
        .find('.collapse-icon')
        .toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    });
});
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrXYGx

Comment: Well, it makes me feel good my jQuery wasn't completely useless! Is there a way to slide it up less than that? or would that be a whole different deal? Because I can hide the photo and the second row if I mess with it long enough, but I still need the first row to remain visible.

Comment: Try adding second `div` within `.form-group` `class` of each `.col-sm-12` container to `$banner` collection

Comment: You are a monster at this Sir! Thank you very much!

Comment: @LOTUSMS See updated post, removed `.add()` , combined selector within single `.find()` call

Comment: There was a backward slash there I didn't recognize. I assume it was  typo. I removed it and didn't affect the code. Was that intentional?

Comment: The backslash was used to place selector string on two lines

Comment: ah. gotcha. Well it works since I put it in one line.